# Center s4-statusbarcontainer

Tags: sharepoint

Best practice to center statusbarcontainer?

I want to cover the entire width with the background color, and center only the text (960px).

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for all layout elements in Firebug (Chrome dev tools or so) to get all desired elements id and their css properties. Create your custom css with new or overwritten properties. Aplly it to your site.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/apply-a-custom-style-sheet-to-a-sharepoint-site-HA010169174.aspx